# In PowerShell, how can I extract a key-value pair from an array of records?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am reading data from a CSV file and want to extract the URL value (abc.com, def.com).  My simple code returns the data in an array of key-value pairs (see below), but I haven't been able to extract an individual item.

@{Product=a; Description=xyz; URL=abc.com}

@{Product=b; Description=abc; URL=def.com}

I tried indexing into the array, using IndexOf, etc.  Any suggestions?

```
    $list = Import-Csv ".\file"

    foreach ($item in $list) {

        write-host $item
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not arrays of key-value pairs, but custom objects created from the rows of your CSV.

You can either use PowerShell's property enumeration behavior to grab all values from the `URL` property of each object:

```
$allURLs = $list.URL
```

Or use `ForEach-Object -MemberName` to grab only a single property value from a collection:

```
$allURLs = $list |ForEach-Object -MemberName URL
```

---

If you need this to run in PowerShell earlier than version 3.0, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$allURLs = $list |Select-Object -ExpandProperty URL
```

Comment: Thank you, grabbing all the URLs ($list.URL did the job!